# SQL Replace Join With Something Faster

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, mysql-workbench

I have a view in SQL that uses a join and takes a lot longer than I would like for it to take. I think it would run much faster if I converted it to a subquery instead, but I'm having trouble with that.

Basically, I want to create a "target" column that calculates the 24h percent change of the price of an asset. Right now, the way I go about it is I create a first view which is the normal table and then a second view which is a copy of the first table but with date+1 that I can then use to calculate the 24h target. Below is my sql code. I am working in MySQL.

```
create view PricesView1 as
select Date,Symbol, avg(Price) as 'Price', avg(BTC_Dominance) as 'BTC_Dominance', 
    pkdummy,pkey from Prices group by Date,pkdummy,pkey, Symbol 
    having right(pkdummy,2)=22 and Date > '2018-11-22';

create view PricesView2 as
select sq.Date, sq.oldDate, sq.Symbol, sq.Price, newP.Price as 'NewPrice',
    newP.BTC_Dominance as 'NewBTCdominance', newP.pkdummy from (
    select date_add(Date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) as 'Date', Date as 'oldDate',Symbol,avg(Price) as 'Price', 
        avg(BTC_Dominance) as 'BTC_Dominance',  pkdummy,pkey from Prices 
        group by Date,date_add(Date, INTERVAL 1 DAY),pkdummy,pkey, Symbol having right(pkdummy,2)=22)sq
    join Prices newP on newP.Date=sq.Date and newP.Symbol=sq.Symbol 
    where right(newP.pkdummy,2)=22 and sq.Date > '2018-11-22' order by datetime desc;

#Use other two views to calculate target
create view priceTarget as
select pv1.Date, pv1.Symbol, avg(pv1.Price) as 'Initial Price', avg(pv2.NewPrice) as 'Price24hLater',
    avg(((pv2.NewPrice-pv1.Price)/pv1.Price)*100) as 'Target24hChange',
    avg(((pv2.NewBTCdominance-pv1.BTC_Dominance)/pv1.BTC_Dominance)*100) as 'BTCdominance24hChange',
    pv1.pkey from PricesView1 pv1 
    join PricesView2 pv2 on pv1.Date=pv2.oldDate and pv1.Symbol=pv2.Symbol
    group by pv1.Date, pv1.Symbol;
```

[Here is a screenshot of the output of the query: 
 SELECT * FROM priceTarget WHERE symbol = 'btc' ORDER BY date desc;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzBWi.png)

Any thoughts on how I can achieve the same result with a faster query that avoids using a join?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

EDIT: I guess it just comes down to the fact that I simply have a lot of data being loaded. I created a new first view to filter my data ahead of time and that reduced the load times from around 32 seconds to just over 10 seconds. Thanks to those who helped!

Comment: One way that will surely speed things up is to not use views, which have very limited access to underlying indexes in MySQL, and are therefore virtually useless.

Comment: I would love to create a single query from this instead of using the views, but I'm not very good at SQL and this helped me make the logic much simpler than a really big single query, which of course would be a better solution. I also heard about using indexes and how that can make queries faster, but again I'm not very good at SQL and don't know how to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the creation of PriceView2 there seems to be some unecessary code

Like the order by at the end and you calculate the Price and BTC but don't use them in the priceTarget view (you use the already available values from PriceView1). I'd think you left it there to have unique date/symbol, you can use a select DISTINCT to achieve the same result.

I don't know if it is intentional but the BTC and price are calculated from an average in PricesView1 and they are not in PricesView2.

This is my suggestion for the PricesView2:

```
create view PricesView2 as
select
    sq.Date,
    newP.Date,
    sq.Symbol,
    newP.Price as 'NewPrice',
    newP.BTC_Dominance as 'NewBTCdominance',
    newP.pkdummy
from (
        select distinct
            Date as 'oldDate',
            Symbol,
            pkdummy,
            pkey
        from Prices 
        having right(pkdummy,2)=22) sq
    join Prices newP on
        newP.Date=date_add(sq.oldDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
        and newP.Symbol=sq.Symbol 
where right(newP.pkdummy,2)=22
and   sq.Date > '2018-11-22'
```

My understanding of views is that they are comparable to macros in other languages: more like code replacement than pre-computation.

So when you do in priceTarget avg(pv1.Price) considering that pv1.Price is defined as avg(Price) you're averaging an average.

In addition to the changes I suggested above I'd change PricesView2 to calculate the new price and BTC average so the priceTarget view doesn't have to

Last in your priceTarget view you should also group by pv1.pkey in addition to pv1.Date and pv1.symbol.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Changing the second view to this brought down the query time from 17.25 seconds to 12.95 seconds. When I wrote this question I was thinking the issue was the join and I wanted to change that, but it seems like that is not the issue. I theorized that replacing the join with a subquery or some logic with variables would be quicker but it doesn't sound like it would be worth doing

Comment: @Ricky good luck then, only 12.9 seconds to go! Just to give you some pointers (I worked only on Sybase) query optimization requires a realistic dataset so you can test, analyzing the query plan and checking the IO which in MySQL seems to be called EXPLAIN. If you can create extra tables, every morning you could fill a PriceTarget table (it's not a perfect solution as you may have to refresh it intraday)..

Comment: thanks for the pointers! I figured I could create a new table that had the data already filtered, instead of having both views use the entire dataset and then filter on that. The 12.95 query now takes 3.25 which seems more reasonable (although a 0.05 query would be pretty sick). I like the idea of creating extra tables, but new data comes in every hour and I think that could get complicated. Thank you for the suggestions! Using "profiles" in MySQL seems to be working pretty well, but I'll look more into explain, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would first do some analysis on the queries themselves to find out what is causing the bottle neck i.e. how the tables are being called, how many rows each table returns, which indexes are being used, etc.  Simple things like reordering the tables in the FROM clause could help performance. Your queries may lacking an index or two that may greatly improve performance.

Comment: While I think that these are all extremely valid points, I'm not convinced that this is an answer, and should perhaps instead be left as a comment